# How do I create a reversible migration helper in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration

I find myself having to execute very similar sql statements (with maybe 1 param besides the table name) on several tables on a rails app. As a result, I'm getting lots of similarly looking migrations, like this one:

```
class DoSomeSQLOnUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    execute('some long sql that alters the user.field1')
    execute('some long sql that alters the user.field2')
  end

  def down
    execute('some sql that undoes the changes')
  end
end
```

Then I have the same thing for clients, sales, etc.

I would like to extend `ActiveRecord::Migration` so that I can do this instead:

```
class DoSomeSQLOnUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    do_custom_thing_on :users, :field1
    do_custom_thing_on :users, :field2
  end
end
```

How can I do that? I think I know how to do it when the operations are separated into up and down, like this:

```
class DoSomeSQLOnUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    do_custom_thing_on :users, :field1
    do_custom_thing_on :users, :field2
  end
  def down
    undo_custom_thing_on :users, :field1
    undo_custom_thing_on :users, :field2
  end
end
```

But doing it so that the change is "reversible" escapes me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be a official supported way to do this, so probably you'll need to open the class `ActiveRecord::Migration::CommandRecorder` and record the new method and its inverted version.

Find the definition of the class at [activerecord/lib/active_record/migration/command_recorder.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/migration/command_recorder.rb).

Answer (score 2):

In Rails 4 there is a [reversible helper method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html#method-i-reversible), which you can use like this:

```
def change
  do_custom_thing_on :users, :field1
  do_custom_thing_on :users, :field2
end

def do_custom_thing_on(table, field)
  reversible do |dir|
    dir.up { execute "some long sql to alter #{field} on #{table}"}
    dir.down { execute "some long sql to undo #{field} on #{table}"}
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you need to do something else, but at least you should add a inverse_custom_thing method to [ActiveRecord::Migration::CommandRecorder](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6012970fea9d3385cd0a515aa353b47d0837d55a/activerecord/lib/active_record/migration/command_recorder.rb)

Answer (score 0):

Main purpose of change method it's adding, renaming columns but not removing. Change method 'knows' how to make reverse when the migration is rolled back. So if you want to do something, which is not removing, just do it in change method, ActiveRecord will reverse it itself, I think.

More information you can get from [official documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html)